# PHP 56 installation via Homebrew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I've used PHP56 installation via Homebrew on my mac for some time now and I am just now getting this error when attempting to run php:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[1]    97410 trace trap  php -v
```

Everything I've searched for online points to openssl version difference with what is shipped with OS X, but as I said I haven't run into this issue for MONTHS (at least) until the past day or 2. (Also, does forcing `link` on openssl via homebrew really break anything as it warns? As that may seem to solve the issue).

I've completely removed anything that I think may have interfered, (rbenv, rvm, wiped and reinstalled homebrew, etc). Has anybody run into this issue? Why is this happening now after everything's been running smoothly for so long?

Comment: It looks like this has since been fixed (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/commit/1c45518275aba98f012f244f3e64140f5cd83d72), `brew update && brew reinstall php56` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding php from source:

```
brew reinstall php56 --build-from-source
```

Looks like openssl was upgraded at the same time and broke PHP.